# Фраза: брызги с раковины будут вечно на плите. Правильно "С" раковины или "ИЗ" раковины?

Tags: предлоги

Предлог "с" выражает пространственное отношение, а именно "направление сверху вниз": спрыгнул с крыши, с дерева, с лестницы. У предлога "из" несколько другое пространственное значение: "направление изнутри наружу" : вышел из комнаты, из школы, из трамвая.
Вода падает СВЕРХУ ВНИЗ
Вода падает НА раковину, значит предлог С раковины вода попадает НА плиту.

То есть мне пытаются доказать, что правильно писать "С" раковины.

Comment: Брызги с поверхности раковины будут вечно на плите. Брызги из ниши раковины будут вечно на плите. А вообще, я бы остановился на слитном написании: сраковины на плите.

Answer (score 3):

На мой взгляд, правильнее говорить:"брызги от раковины".
Здесь раковина является отправной точкой, от которой, собственно, брызги и начинают свой полёт.

Answer (score 0):

Разберемся с раковиной.

[РАКОВИНА](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0) - вместилище с воронкой, расположенное под водопроводным краном для отвода использованной воды.

Если вот такая -

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вполне подойдёт предлог "с" - вон у неё какие бортики широкие, с них и полетят (если напор воды сильный) брызги.

А ежели такая:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
уже "из".

Предлог "с" зависит не от *сверху вниз*, а *с одного места на другое.*

А вторая констракшн прямо-таки предназначена для демонстрации применения предлога "из".